# jquery mouseleave trigger when over a a href link

Tags: jquery, mouseevent

I have a div menu to show up and on mouseleave the div, it hides itself.
The problem is I have href links in the menu div and when the mouse is over the link, mouseleave is trigger. It's not the effect I want obviously. I've tried mouseout and hover but has the same effect.

Any insight would be great. Thanks.

Comment: We need the **relevant** code please.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a problem with mouseout and mouseover rather than mouseenter and mouseleave. With the former combination you can get unexpected over events and if you're using "toggle" rather than setting a value directly it can seem like it received a mouseleave.

The example [at the bottom](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) explains the two scenarios rather nicely if seeing it visually is of assistance. Using jsfiddle or providing some code really goes a long way in helping to solve these kind of problems as well.

Feel free to use [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/v556w/2/) to demonstrate your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there's no other element with a z-index that spoils the fun